# SonarQube upgrade

Tags: java, sonarqube, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade SonarQube from 4.1.2 to 5.1. I have the following plugins in my extensions/plugins:

- sonar-cobertura-plugin-3.3.2.jar
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.2.jar
- sonar-java-plugin-3.2.1.jar
- sonar-pmd-plugin-3.3.2.jar

and it still fails to upgrade with the following error.

```
2015.04.30 12:34:29 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2015.04.30 12:34:31 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
org/sonar/api/batch/maven/MavenPluginHandler
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPlugin.getExtensions(CoberturaPlugin.java:48)
org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:51)
org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.startLevel4Components(ServerComponents.java:819)
org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:120)
org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: We can't help you if you're giving wrong information => the list of plugins you are giving is not possible, because Coberura latest version is 1.6.3, Findbugs is 3.2, Java is 3.1 and PMD is 2.3. What's more, you're giving a partial log. So please copy-paste the full log so that we can see all your environment configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems that look like yours when upgrading http://qualilogy.com/en/sonarqube-upgrade/.
I recommand you read the Java Plugin page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin, I suspect this is the source of your problem.

Regards.